# How do i get a specific variable from arraylist element?

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an arraylist where in one class i have the instance variables as well as the get and set methods. In the other class i have initialised the arraylist as below and also added some elements to it.

```
private ArrayList<Student> students;

    public StudentCollection() {
        students = new ArrayList<Student>();
        students.add(new Student("Tom", 10));
        students.add(new Student("Dick", 11));
        students.add(new Student("Harry", 12));
    }
```

I would like to return the second variable (the integers e.g. 10,11,12) from each of the three elements so that i can use them in my interface. How would i do this.

Comment: To answer this, we'd have to see the `Student` class. Assuming `Student` has a `getName()` and `getId()` methods, the answer would be `students.get(i).getId()`

Comment: What exactly do you want to return? Is it an `ArrayList<Integer>`?

Comment: @Arkadiy yes the Student class has all the get and set methods as well as a toString method.

Comment: OK, as @4castle asked - you cannot return a variable. Do you need a list of IDs? Please show the desired return type.

Answer (score 2):

You can grab all the values for a given property using Java 8's functional stream mapping.

I wrote a generic method to make it easier to call.

### Collector

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Collector {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();

        students.add(new Student("Tom", 10));
        students.add(new Student("Dick", 11));
        students.add(new Student("Harry", 12));

        List<Integer> grades = valueGrabber(students, s -> s.getGrade());

        System.out.println(grades); // [10, 11, 12]
    }

    private static <C, T> List<T> valueGrabber(List<C> items, Function<C, T> func) {
        return items.stream().map(func).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

### Student

```
public class Student {
    private String name;
    private int grade;

    public String getName() { return name; }
    public int getGrade() { return grade; }

    public Student(String name, int grade) {
        this.name = name;
        this.grade = grade;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to extract the numbers from your students iteratively, like

```
int[] ids = new int[students.size()];
for (int i = 0; i < students.size(); i++) {
  ids[i] = students.get(i).getID();
}
return ids;
```

Comment: I already tried this yesterday. But when i try to print it the error i get in eclipse console like "[Ljava.lang.String;@36dfb101"

Comment: "[Ljava.lang.String;@36dfb101" this is the output you get from calling toString on an array ([])

Answer (score 0):

> I  would like to return the second variable (the integers e.g. 10,11,12) from each of the three elements so that i can use them in my interface. How would i do this.

To get a **specific element** from the arraylist:

```
students.get(2);  //returns 3rd Student element
```

> I already tried this yesterday. But when i try to print it the error i get in eclipse console like "[Ljava.lang.String;@36dfb101"

You have been trying to print a String array directly. Instead of printing the entire array, do:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(stringArray));  //to print entire array
```

**OR**

```
System.out.println(stringArray[x]);  //where x is index of an element to be printed
```

---

To get a **specific attribute** from the element from the arraylist:

```
students.get(2).getName();  //returns 3rd Student's name
students.get(2).getAge();   //returns 3rd Student's age
```

If you print the your Student object directly, the `toString()` will be implicitly invoked, which gives you `className + "@" + hashCode`.

If you want to print your Student object directly, and you wish to alter the String representation of your class, you can override the `toString()` method:

```
//E.g. Print student's name when printing the object directly
class Student{
    //class members & constructors
    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return getName();
    }
}
```

Comment: `[Ljava.lang.String;@36dfb101` would mean they tried to output a `String[]`